# backbone.js tutorial: how does the url method work?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

tutorial: http://www.jamesyu.org/2011/01/27/cloudedit-a-backbone-js-tutorial-by-example/
I am going through the CloudEdit rails/backbone.js tutrorial and got stuck on the very first chunk of code. here it is:

```
var Document = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url : function() {
    var base = 'documents';
    if (this.isNew()) return base;
    return base + (base.charAt(base.length - 1) == '/' ? '' : '/') + this.id;
  }
});
```

the line I am struggling with is this

```
return base + (base.charAt(base.length - 1) == '/' ? '' : '/') + this.id;
```

Since `base = 'documents'` isn't `base.charAt(base.length - 1) = s` ? 
I know what it is supposed to do, I am just wondering why it does it. Does the value of base change to `documents/` sometimes? Why not just write `return base+'/'+this.id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That line is the equivalent of

```
if last character is '/'
   return base + this.id
else 
   return base + '/' + this.id
```

just having `return base+'/'+this.id` would result in a url of "documents//6" for a model with `base="documents/"` and `id=6`

*Update*
As Adam Lassek mentioned in the comments, that line of should simply be written as

```
return base+'/'+this.id
```

for this example as the `base` variable is defined in that same block. However that line of code is also in [the backbone.js source code](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-43) and its purpose is as described above.

Instead of overriding the `url` method you should set the `urlRoot` attribute in the model:

```
var Document = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot : 'documents'
});
```

Comment: Considering that the base url is defined at the top of the function, this code is entirely superfluous. What a terrible example.

Comment: @AdamLassek Very true, looks like they copy/pasted out of backbone.js source code and just changed the declaration of base rather than setting a urlRoot attribute.

Comment: @SpencerCooley You are correct, I didn't notice that at first. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Oh ok, that link makes more sense. I was thinking that maybe base was some sort of special backbone.js word that changed dynamically.

Comment: Oh, I actually didn't know about `urlRoot`. Thanks for the update!